# FIlter Gmail API label ids with AND condition

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I set up a workflow to trigger an appscript when some emails are received.

At a high level, the steps are:

1. New - i.e. unread - messages that match some criteria are automatically starred using a gmail rule.
2. When the email is starred, gmail API publishes a message to a pub/sub topic.
3. The pub/sub topic has one push subscription. The subscription is my appscript code deployed as a web app.
4. The appscript code performs some tasks and unstars and marks as read the original email that triggered the process.

Everything works pretty well. However, I noticed that messages are published to the pub/sub topic when they are unstarred, too. This makes sense since I am asking the gmail API to monitor all my starred messages. Anyways, this trigger a useless appscript run and I would like to get rid of this double notification.

I am trying to keep this as simple as possible.

I am passing the following body to the POST request to the gmail watch endpoint:

```
{
  "labelIds": ["STARRED"],
  "topicName": "projects/mytopic/topics/myemail",
  "labelFilterBehavior": "INCLUDE"
}
```

I tried a very basic tweak and added the UNREAD `labelIds`:

```
{
  "labelIds": ["STARRED", "UNREAD"],
  "topicName": "projects/mytopic/topics/myemail",
  "labelFilterBehavior": "INCLUDE"
}
```

But this seems to work with a "OR" logic. That is, the gmail API publishes all messages that are either starred or unread.

Is there any way I can make this work with a "AND" logic, meaning that the gmail API publishes all messages that are both starred and unread?
Do you have any suggestion to achieve my goal in other ways?